# Excel Multiple Dynamic Charts

Tags: excel, vba, charts, excel-charts, dynamic-chart-series

I have some excel data which I have variable number of Columns. The data is like the one shown in the picture but have longer trend

[image]

Now, I want to have sepearate sheet where I will only few column names, e.g. A,b,c and charts should be made on the basis of this, i.e it should match the column_name mentioned in the data(alongwith the values) with the one in the separate sheet and plot the 3 charts in a row. After creating 3 charts it should create new charts below them. Is there any way to do it in excel? where each plot will be against datetime, i.e. datetime vs A, datetime vs B etc whatever is in the list will be plotted against datetime

Comment: Yes you can do this. Take a look at pivot tables and pivot charts.

Comment: Actually requirement is to use charts only. Not sure why but,Can I only use charts to achieve the same?